# Why can't Pipenv find the correct version of python for my venv?

Tags: python, pipenv, pyenv

I need a little assistance with an issue I'm having with one of my venvs.

## TLDR

With a fresh virtual environment created with `pipenv`, running `pipenv run python --version` returns the following message, along with the wrong python version:

```
Warning: the which -a system utility is required for Pipenv to find Python installations properly.
  Please install it.
Python 3.9.7 <--- this should be 3.8.5
```

Activating the virtual environment and then running `python --version` shows the correct version, but this prevents me from running anything via `pipenv run <any command>` with the venv not activated, and also raises suspicion that something isn't quite right. This is on MacOS Big Sur 11.6

## My Process

1. Install my desired python version with `pyenv install 3.8.5`:

```
$ pyenv install 3.8.5                                                             
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.5.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.5/Python-3.8.5.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.5...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Installed Python-3.8.5 to /Users/<me>/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5
```

Output of `pyenv versions`:

```
* system (set by /Users/<me>/.pyenv/version)
  3.6.4
  3.6.7
  3.8.12
  3.8.5
  3.9.1
```

2. Create new environment and install reqs from Pipfile with `pipenv install --dev`. Pipfile contains

```
[requires]
python_full_version = "3.8.5"
```

Output:

```
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /Users/<me>/dev/<project>/Pipfile
Using /Users/<me>/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/bin/python3.8 (3.8.5) to create virtualenv...
⠦ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.8.5.final.0-64 in 325ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/Users/<me>/.local/share/virtualenvs/<project>-OYt9MQn5, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/<me>/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==21.1.2, setuptools==57.0.0, wheel==0.36.2
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

✔ Successfully created virtual environment! 
Virtualenv location: /Users/<me>/.local/share/virtualenvs/<project>-OYt9MQn5
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (62a518)...
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 108/108 — 00:00:50
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
```

3. Try to run `pipenv run python --version` (it finds the wrong one):

```
$ pipenv run python --version
Loading .env environment variables...
Warning: the which -a system utility is required for Pipenv to find Python installations properly.
  Please install it.
Python 3.9.7
```

4. Activate the shell, and run either the above command (with the same output), or just `python --version`, since the shell is activated now, and it finds the correct version:

```
(<project>) $ pipenv shell 
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Loading .env environment variables...
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
 . /Users/<me>/.local/share/virtualenvs/<project>-OYt9MQn5/bin/activate
N/A: version "N/A -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install N/A" to install it before using it.
 $  . /Users/ckz8780/.local/share/virtualenvs/<project>-OYt9MQn5/bin/activate
(<project>) $ python --version 
Python 3.8.5
(<project>) $
```

FWIW, I have several other venvs I've created in the exact same way (or so I thought) which work fine. In those venvs, when I run `pipenv run python --version` with the venv deactivated, the `which -a` error isn't there and they find the right python version. In fact, even if I activate the shell in those venvs and run `pipenv run python --version`, it still works fine and finds the right one. The only difference in those venvs is the python version (two are using python v3.6.x, and two are using python v3.8.9). They all work as expected, but this one just will not seem to find the right version no matter what I do. I am pulling my hair out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar workflow when it comes to installing Python (using both Pyenv and Pipenv).

This is working for me:

1. Install new Python version with Pyenv:

```
pyenv install 3.9.0
```

2. Run pyenv shell

```
pyenv shell 3.9.0
```

3. In pyenv shell install pipenv via pip

```
pip install pipenv
```

4. With pipenv install packages ...

```
pipenv install ...
```

5. Finally create a virtualenv via Pipenv that is using the Python version from Pyenv:

```
pipenv shell 3.9.0
```

Output:

```
Pipfile: /Users/fabianmeyer/Desktop/analytics/Pipfile
Using /Users/fabianmeyer/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/bin/python3.9 (3.9.0) to create virtualenv...
⠹ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.9.0.final.0-64 in 1824ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/Users/fabianmeyer/.local/share/virtualenvs/analytics-GC4g190F, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/fabianmeyer/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==22.0.3, setuptools==60.6.0, wheel==0.37.1
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator

✔ Successfully created virtual environment! 
Virtualenv location: /Users/fabianmeyer/.local/share/virtualenvs/analytics-GC4g190F
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying an answer from a [pipenv GitHub issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1048#issuecomment-343167383):

> This is not how pipenv works, you can’t call it to run something from
> inside a virtualenv it is managing. Pipenv is installed externally to
> the virtualenv, which means you use `pipenv run` the same way you use
> `pipenv install` — without ever activating the environment directly.
> That’s part of the reason why pipenv exists, so that you won’t have to
> activate environments or even worry about where they might be— this is
> handled for you.
>
> Since pipenv isn’t installed inside the environments it manages, this
> makes sense. I’m going to close this issue since it’s not a problem
> with pipenv and since this information is covered in a bunch of other
> issues

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the response. I did find that issue and wanted to ask for more clarification about it but unfortunately they locked it so I couldn't respond. I don't think that applies to this situation, as I'm not trying to run `pipenv run` within my virtual environment. I'm running it *without* the venv activated, so I was under the impression that it would activate the venv and then run the command within it on the fly. Is that not accurate? If that's not right, why does it work on all my other venvs?